# Encapsulation in the age of frameworks

Tags: frameworks, dependency-injection, constructor, encapsulation

At my old C++ job, we always took great care in encapsulating member variables, and only exposing them as properties when absolutely necessary.  We'd have really specific constructors that made sure you fully constructed the object before using it.

These days, with ORM frameworks, dependency-injection, serialization, etc., it seems like you're better off just relying on the default constructor and exposing everything about your class in properties, so that you can inject things, or build and populate objects more dynamically.

In C#, it's been taken one step further with Object initializers, which give you the ability to basically define your own constructor.  (I know object initializers are not really custom constructors, but I hope you get my point.)

Are there any general concerns with this direction?  It seems like encapsulation is starting to become less important in favor of convenience.

EDIT: I know you can still carefully encapsulate members, but I just feel like when you're trying to crank out some classes, you either have to sit and carefully think about how to encapsulate each member, or just expose it as a property, and worry about how it is initialized later.  It just seems like the easiest approach these days is to expose things as properties, and not be so careful.  Maybe I'm just flat wrong, but that's just been my experience, espeically with the new C# language features.

Comment: Don't let anyone fool you, those object initializers are just syntactic sugar.

Comment: I know object initializers aren't really constructors, but that's not my point.  They allow you to construct an object using the default constructor and set properties by hand.

Comment: Not really sure what difference is between those and just typing out each statement to set each property. But ok.

Comment: "Don't let anyone fool you," I understand what an object initializer is doing, that is not the point I'm trying to discuss.  If you feel the need to point out obvious things, can you leave out the condescending bullshit next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I disagree with your conclusion. There are many good ways of encapsulating in c# with all the above mentioned technologies, as to maintain good software coding practices. I would also say that it depends on whose technology demo you're looking at, but in the end it comes down to reducing the state-space of your objects so that you can make sure they hold their invariants at all times.

Take **object relational frameworks**; most of them allow you to specify how they are going to hydrate the entities; NHibernate for example allows you so say `access="property"` or `access="field.camelcase"` and similar. This allows you to encapsulate your properties.

**Dependency injection** works on the other types you have, mostly those which are not entities, even though you can combine AOP+ORM+IOC in some very nice ways to improve the state of these things. IoC is often used from layers above your domain entities if you're building a data-driven application, which I guess you are, since you're talking about ORMs.

They ("they" being application and domain services and other intrinsic classes to the program) expose their dependencies but in fact can be encapsulated and tested in even better isolation than previously since the paradigms of design-by-contract/design-by-interface which you often use when mocking dependencies in mock-based testing (in conjunction with IoC), will move you towards class-as-component "semantics". I mean: every class, when built using the above, will be better encapsulated.

*Updated for urig:* This holds true for both exposing concrete **dependencies** and exposing interfaces. First about interfaces: What I was hinting at above was that services and other applications classes which have dependencies, can with OOP depend on contracts/interfaces rather than specific implementations. In C/C++ and older languages there wasn't the interface and abstract classes can only go so far. Interfaces allow you to tie different runtime instances to the same interface without having to worry about leaking internal state which is what you're trying to get away from when abstracting and encapsulating. With abstract classes you can still provide a class implementation, just that you can't instantiate it, but inheritors still need to know about the invariants in your implementation and that can mess up state.

Secondly, about concrete classes as properties: you have to be wary about what types of types ;) you expose as properties. Say you have a List in your instance; then don't expose IList as the property; this will probably leak and you can't guarantee that consumers of the interface don't add things or remove things which you depend on; instead expose something like IEnumerable and return a copy of the List, or even better, do it as a method:
public IEnumerable MyCollection { get { return _List.Enum(); } } and you can be 100% certain to get both the performance and the encapsulation. Noone can add or remove to that IEnumerable and you still don't have to perform a costly array copy. The corresponding helper method:

```
static class Ext {
    public static IEnumerable<T> Enum<T>(this IEnumerable<T> inner) {
        foreach (var item in inner) yield return item;
    }
}
```

So while you can't get 100% encapsulation in say creating overloaded equals operators/method you can get close with your public interfaces.

You can also use the new features of .Net 4.0 built on Spec# to verify the contracts I talked about above.

**Serialization** will always be there and has been for a long time. Previously, before the internet-area it was used for saving your object graph to disk for later retrieval, now it's used in web services, in copy-semantics and when passing data to e.g. a browser. This doesn't necessarily break encapsulation if you put a few [NonSerialized] attributes or the equivalents on the correct fields.

Object initializers aren't the same as constructors, they are just a way of collapsing a few lines of code. Values/instances in the {} will not be assigned until all of your constructors have run, so in principle it's just the same as not using object initializers.

I guess, what you have to watch out for is deviating from the good principles you've learnt from your previous job and make sure you are keeping your domain objects filled with business logic encapsulated behind good interfaces and ditto for your service-layer.

Comment: Hi Henrik,

Can you give an example of how "They expose their dependencies but in fact can be encapsulated and tested in even better isolation than previously"? 

If a class exposes its dependencies in public properties, how can that not violate encapsulation?

Thanks!
urig

Comment: Coming back, looking at this, I see I was fuzzy in what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

Private members are still incredibly important.  Controlling access to internal object data is always good, and shouldn't be ignored.

Many times private methods I've found to be overkill.  Most of the time, if the work you're doing is important enough to break out, you can refactor it in such a way that either a) the private method is trivial, or b) is an integral part of other functions.

In addition, with unit testing, having many methods private makes it very hard to unit test.  There are ways around that (making test objects friends, etc), but add difficulties.

I wouldn't discount private methods entirely though.  Any time there's important, internal algorithms that really make no sense outside of the class there's no reason to expose those methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think that encapsulation is still important, it helps more in libraries than anything imho.  You can create a library that does X, but you don't need everyone to know how X was created.  And if you wanted to create it more specifically to obfuscate the way you create X.  The way I learned about encapsulation, I remember also that you should always define your variables as private to protect them from a data attack.  To protect against a hacker breaking your code and accessing variables that they are not supposed to use.