# Should I inject a HashSet for storing listeners to achieve testability?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing

I've seen this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943704/should-i-inject-objects-needed-for-execution-of-an-algorithm-should-i-inject-ev) which may look like a duplicate but it doesn't explain two problems that I face: testability and mutability.

I have a class that implements the observable pattern. To  make it simple, let's imagine it like this:

```
public class Observable {
    private final Set<Listener> listeners;

    public Observable(final Set<Listener> listeners) {
        this.listeners = listeners;
    }

    public Observable() {
        listeners = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public void registerListener(Listener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void unregisterListener(Listener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }
}
```

I created two constructors to show two options I am trying to choose from. I want to test this implementation and I cannot achieve it if I don't inject a set for my listeners from the outside. On the other hand, if I inject it I make it possible to mutate this object elsewhere and my implementation is not that safe.

Is there a way to achieve both testability and safety in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the constructor that you created for testing packaged private, that would decrease the accessibility of this ctor and let users know that it is not something they should be using. Put your tests in the same package and you should be able to access this ctor.

change this:

```
public Observable(final Set<Listener> pListeners) {
        // here pListeners is immutable
        this.listeners = new HashSet(pListeners);
    }
```

to this:

```
Observable(final Set<Listener> pListeners) {
        // here pListeners is immutable
        this.listeners = new HashSet(pListeners);
    }
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

If immutability is you main concern during testing. You can use Immutable Sets.

**Core Java**

```
Collections.unmodifiableSet(listeners)
```

It still will return a `java.util.Set` but with an immutable property

**Using libraries (e.g Guava)**

```
Set<String> immutable = ImmutableSet.of(listener1, listener2);
```

For your requirement to manipulate the set only inside a certain class, you can create your own copy of the Set ([deep copy](https://www.baeldung.com/java-deep-copy)) that is unaccessable  from outside the class.

In the other hand you can instantiate your Set with immutable Sets  as show above.

here is a full example

```
public class Observable {
    private Set<Listener> listeners;

    public Observable(final Set<Listener> pListeners) {
        // here pListeners is immutable
        this.listeners = new HashSet(pListeners);
    }

    public Observable() {
        listeners = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public void registerListener(Listener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void unregisterListener(Listener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }
}
```

That being said JLS specifies :

> final fields also allow programmers to implement thread-safe immutable objects without synchronization. A thread-safe immutable
>   object is seen as immutable by all threads, even if a data race is
>   used to pass references to the immutable object between threads. This
>   can provide safety guarantees against misuse of an immutable class by
>   incorrect or malicious code. final fields must be used correctly to
>   provide a guarantee of immutability.
>
> The usage model for final fields is a simple one: Set the final fields for an object in that object's constructor; and do not write a
>   reference to the object being constructed in a place where another
>   thread can see it before the object's constructor is finished. If this
>   is followed, then when the object is seen by another thread, that
>   thread will always see the correctly constructed version of that
>   object's final fields. It will also see versions of any object or
>   array referenced by those final fields that are at least as up-to-date
>   as the final fields are.

Comment: I need to mutate this set from the inside of Observable so I can register and unregister listeners. I don't want this object to be accessible anywhere else, but it will be if I inject it.

Comment: I see, but with this solution, I cannot test registerListener() and un registerListener() methods again. So I am still stuck with either keeping my instance safe or being able to mock it and test it.

Comment: If there is no way to achieve both goals, I could use an advice on what is the best practice here.

Comment: I don't know how you could not use yours methods as your set is wrapped inside the class but still modifiable !? It is the Sets that you instanciates you class with that should be immutable

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you. If I receive an immutable set I cannot mutate it by adding and removing listeners. If I make a copy of this set inside constructor I will gain a possibility to mutate my new set, but I won't be able to mock it for testing purpose, because it will be created inside this class.